# Captura de pantalla en Android (Telefono)

Tags: android, android-studio, captcha

He logrado capturar la pantalla en Android, pero solo es de la aplicación que lo invoca, es decir no toma la captura del teléfono.

```
//Como se invoca el metodo
capturaPantalla(getWindow().getDecorView());


private File capturaPantalla(View v) {
    View rootview = v.getRootView();
    rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = rootview.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
    String fechaComoCadena = sdf.format(new Date());

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + fechaComoCadena + ".jpg");
    try {
        if (file.createNewFile()) {
            try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                outputStream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return file;
}
```

He buscado información al respecto pero no he logrado dar con ninguna solución satisfactoria.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una respuesta tomada del sitio de SO en inglés que almacena la captura en la tarjeta SD:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android

Primero necesitas habilitar los permisos para guardar el archivo en la tarjeta:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Y este es el código:

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

        // create bitmap screen capture
        View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        openScreenshot(imageFile);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema de esa solución es que solo saca capturas de pantalla a la App con lo invoca, de esta forma si se deja en segundo plano no saca la foto a teléfono.

Comment: revisa este blog, parece que tiene la respuesta a lo que necesitas: http://devdeeds.com/take-screenshot-programmatically/

Comment: Realiza lo mismo captura solo la imagen  de la APP que lo invoca